# Set image color to match background color php

Tags: php, html, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I am using `Imagemagick` to work with images in `php`. I am no-wise in `ImageMagick` so could not do it. I have 2 Pictures, 1 is background and other one is above it. The one which is on top is of gray color png. While the background image can be any image. I want to set my top image's color to match the most color of background image.

For Example, this is a random background image which has beige/pink as its main color

[image]

and this is my top image

[image]

I want my above top image to change its color to match the most color of background image, as in the above image, it should be something like

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't feel like writing and debugging a load of PHP today, but can show you some techniques on the command line that you should be able to translate into PHP.

You can get the mean of the background image by resizing it to a single 1x1 pixel and then printing its value in RGB terms:

```
convert background.jpg -scale 1x1 -format "%[pixel:p{0,0}]" info:
srgb(219,199,164)
```

If I take that value and make a solid square out of it, you can see it is a beige colour like you suggest:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:"srgb(219,199,164)" mean.png
```

[image]

You can probably use [getImageChannelStatistics()](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagechannelstatistics.php)
in PHP for that.

If I now take that colour, and make it the fill colour for tinting and apply a tint, I get this:

```
convert top.png -fill "srgb(219,199,164)" -tint 100% result.png
```

[image]

In PHP, you'd be looking at [tintImage()](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.tintimage.php).

Something horrible has happened down the right side - I don't understand that, but if I extract the opacity from your top image and re-apply it to the result image, it goes away:

```
convert top.png -alpha extract alpha.pgm
convert top.png -fill "srgb(219,199,164)" -tint 100% alpha.pgm -compose copyopacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you for sharing your insights and experience. Do you know what is going on down the right-hand side of the image? Or why I needed to copy the opacity of the original image again please?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted my comment before Mark's comment above. What I had said was that I recommend using -colorspace sRGB for normal (non-linear) color rather than -colorspace RGB for linear (and darker) color.

Comment: Mark, your simple tint command (ending in result.png) worked fine for me. I do not see any stripes on the right side using IM 6.9.8.3 Q16 Mac OSX. Perhaps it is the upload process changing the image format or removing the transparency. If I remove the transparency, it shows the stripes. Note, also that you should always add -alpha off before -compose copy_opacity. But that is later in your processing.

Comment: P.S. This upload system or host is rather strange. I tried to make examples of the average color as swatches using RGB and sRGB and the RGB one is darker for me on my computer, but when I uploaded it, it showed lighter. So I deleted that post.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell for your kind help. I had already solved the problem and as you suggested. But for you help, I am upvoting and selecting your answered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it myself through these 2 lines of codes

```
exec("convert fabric.jpg -scale 1x1\! -format '%[pixel:u]' info:-", $a);
exec('convert arm-shadow.png -fuzz 10% -fill "'.$a[0].'" +opaque black -fill "'.$a[0].'" -opaque black foo.png');
```